# Rounding a number away from zero in c#

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding

In my database, I have three point floating numbers columns and a process that multiplies the two first ones to get the third one value

`item.ValorTotal = Math.Round(item.Qtde * item.ValorUnitario, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

but if my item.Qtde is like 0.03 and my item.ValorUnitario is 0.02, item.ValorTotal the result is 0.0006 and the variable receives zero because of the round, how do I can round to get 0.01 and continue using two numbers after decimal point?

In short I do like to round to the first possible number (0.01) when I receive a lower number like 0.006 or 0.0006

Comment: You want to round `0.0006` and get `0.01`?

Comment: If it was 0.0106 should it be 0.02 then?

Comment: Also, what's the `ValorTotal` type?

Comment: I think that you're mistaking 0.0006 for 0.006. There's no possible world in which 0.0006 should be rounded to 0.01.

Comment: @SᴇM Yes, my floating point number can only handle two numbers after the decimal point.

ValorTotal is decimal, like item.Qtde and item.ValorUnitario

Comment: @Ralf no, 0.0106 should round normally, to 0.01

Comment: And 0 should also be 0.01 then? So you want't to have rounding but at least a minimum value of 0.01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Math.Round()` you can use `Math.Ceiling()`.

The `Math.Ceiling()` method in `C#` is used to return the smallest integral value greater than or equal to the specified number.

So in your code example it will be something like:

```
item.ValorTotal = (Math.Ceiling((item.Qtde * item.ValorUnitario) * 100) / 100);
```

Output:

```
0,0006 => 0,01
0,0106 => 0,02
```

Answer (score 0):

AwayFromZero doesn't mean that you always round upward. In real it works at most values like usual rounding. As far as I understood it only has an effect if you would round 0.005x.
Therefore write

```
item.ValorTotal = Math.Round(item.Qtde * item.ValorUnitario + 0.005, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

when you want to round upward and both values are positive.